# Problemas clase anidada java Web services

Tags: java, webservice, clase-anidada

Tengo la siguiente clase que me genero al hacer conexión a una web services, esta clase se llama StringMap:

```
package entidades;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Clase Java para stringMap complex type.
 * 
 * <p>El siguiente fragmento de esquema especifica el contenido que se espera que haya en esta clase.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="stringMap">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="values">
 *           &lt;complexType>
 *             &lt;complexContent>
 *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 &lt;sequence>
 *                   &lt;element name="entry" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
 *                     &lt;complexType>
 *                       &lt;complexContent>
 *                         &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                           &lt;sequence>
 *                             &lt;element name="key" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *                             &lt;element name="value" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *                           &lt;/sequence>
 *                         &lt;/restriction>
 *                       &lt;/complexContent>
 *                     &lt;/complexType>
 *                   &lt;/element>
 *                 &lt;/sequence>
 *               &lt;/restriction>
 *             &lt;/complexContent>
 *           &lt;/complexType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "stringMap", propOrder = {
    "values"
})
public class StringMap {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected StringMap.Values values;

    /**
     * Obtiene el valor de la propiedad values.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link StringMap.Values }
     *     
     */
    public StringMap.Values getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    /**
     * Define el valor de la propiedad values.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link StringMap.Values }
     *     
     */
    public void setValues(StringMap.Values value) {
        this.values = value;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Clase Java para anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>El siguiente fragmento de esquema especifica el contenido que se espera que haya en esta clase.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element name="entry" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
     *           &lt;complexType>
     *             &lt;complexContent>
     *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *                 &lt;sequence>
     *                   &lt;element name="key" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
     *                   &lt;element name="value" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
     *                 &lt;/sequence>
     *               &lt;/restriction>
     *             &lt;/complexContent>
     *           &lt;/complexType>
     *         &lt;/element>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "entry"
    })
    public static class Values {

        protected List<StringMap.Values.Entry> entry;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the entry property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
         * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
         * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
         * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the entry property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
         * <pre>
         *    getEntry().add(newItem);
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         * <p>
         * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
         * {@link StringMap.Values.Entry }
         * 
         * 
         */
        public List<StringMap.Values.Entry> getEntry() {
            if (entry == null) {
                entry = new ArrayList<StringMap.Values.Entry>();
            }
            return this.entry;
        }


        /**
         * <p>Clase Java para anonymous complex type.
         * 
         * <p>El siguiente fragmento de esquema especifica el contenido que se espera que haya en esta clase.
         * 
         * <pre>
         * &lt;complexType>
         *   &lt;complexContent>
         *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
         *       &lt;sequence>
         *         &lt;element name="key" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
         *         &lt;element name="value" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
         *       &lt;/sequence>
         *     &lt;/restriction>
         *   &lt;/complexContent>
         * &lt;/complexType>
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         */
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "key",
            "value"
        })
        public static class Entry {

            protected String key;
            protected String value;

            /**
             * Obtiene el valor de la propiedad key.
             * 
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public String getKey() {
                return key;
            }

            /**
             * Define el valor de la propiedad key.
             * 
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public void setKey(String value) {
                this.key = value;
            }

            /**
             * Obtiene el valor de la propiedad value.
             * 
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public String getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            /**
             * Define el valor de la propiedad value.
             * 
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public void setValue(String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Esta es la función que me genero :

```
private static String startConversationWithData(long idConversation, java.lang.String tableCode, entidades.StringMap values) throws InternalDanaException_Exception {
    entidades.ConversationWS_Service service = new entidades.ConversationWS_Service();
    entidades.ConversationWS port = service.getConversationWSPort();
    return port.startConversationWithData(idConversation, tableCode, values);
}
```

Tengo problemas al mandar el tercer parámetro "entidades.StringMap values"...
ya que tengo q pasarle varios valores de KEY y value (Lista).

```
        StringMap.Values.Entry entry = new StringMap.Values.Entry();
        List<StringMap.Values.Entry> listentry = new ArrayList<StringMap.Values.Entry>();
        entidades.StringMap.Values valores = new entidades.StringMap.Values();
        entidades.StringMap map = new entidades.StringMap();

    entry.setKey("CAMPO_1");
    entry.setValue("AAAAA");
    listentry.add(entry);

    entry.setKey("CAMPO_2");
    entry.setValue("BBBBBB");
    listentry.add(entry);

    entry.setKey("CAMPO_3");
    entry.setValue("CCCCCCC");
    listentry.add(entry);       

    entry.setKey("CAMPO_4");
    entry.setValue("DDDDDD");
    listentry.add(entry);        

    entry.setKey("CAMPO_5");
    entry.setValue("FFFFFFF");
    listentry.add(entry);
```

Saludos cordiales,